# Magento 2: how to change simple product's status when stock is 0?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product

I just added 1 configurable product (tshirt) with 3 sizes available.

I did a test buy and noticed that when a size is out of stock, still appears as an available size on the product page. Then if user selects that size, magento shows the "This item is out of stock" message.

This can be solved by setting manually the simple product size to "Disabled".

Is it possible that the status changes from "enabled" to "disabled" automatically when a size is out of stock?

Comment: Looks like a bag, please create  issue on github

Comment: I am looking for same function, did you found any solution?

Comment: This is probably by design. Not everyone wants to hide their products from customers when they're out of stock.